# Applescript : wait that the page is load on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript, document-ready

```
tell application "Safari"
        repeat until (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in tab 2 of window 1) is "complete"
        end repeat
    end tell
end if
```

how can I have this working with Chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
repeat until (execute tab 1 of window 1 javascript "document.readyState" is "complete")
end repeat
    execute tab 1 of window 1 javascript "document.readyState"
end tell
```

but you may have pages that return "interactive" forever, or for a very long time.

Doing it with just AppleScript is supposed to be:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat until (loading of tab 1 of window 1 is false)
        1 + 1 --just an arbitary line
    end repeat
    loading of tab 1 of window 1 --this just returns final status
end tell
```

but, to tell you the truth, I find it suspicious. I have a page that's pretty bare html in the body (http://www.crgreen.com/boethos/boethos.html), and it works with that, but for most pages (I've tried yahoo, macupdate, bbc news, jedit.org, etc.) I'm not getting a "loading = true", ever. It may be buggy.

Comment: thank you ! I will try all that in a minutes, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

For Chromium browsers (Google Chrome, Brave Browser, Microsoft Edge, Opera, Vivaldi, …) you don’t need JavaScript workarounds, as they have proper support for checking if a tab is still loading.

In AppleScript:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to return loading of tab 2 of window 1
```

In JavaScript for Automation (JXA):

```js
Application('Google Chrome').windows[1].tabs[2].loading()
```