# How to "Wait until web page loaded" in Firefox (applescript)?

Tags: firefox, applescript, automator

This code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292181/applescript-wait-that-the-page-is-load-on-chrome/68740017#68740017) works perfect, but doesn't work in Firefox. Why and how to fix it in applescript?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat until (loading of tab 1 of window 1 is false)
        1 + 1 --just an arbitary line
    end repeat
    loading of tab 1 of window 1 --this just returns final status
end tell
```

Comment: **Stack Overflow** is not a _code_ debugging/writing service. What have you tried? Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) &  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As **Firefox** does not contain a specific **AppleScript** *dictionary*, e.g. **Firefox.sdef** *file*, it is not considered to be **AppleScript** *scriptable* in the same way as e.g. **Google Chrome**, and while it will respond to some of the basic *commands*, such as `activate`, `quit`, etc., it will require **UI Scripting** to do what you are asking.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* requires **Firefox** version 87 or newer, and setting its `accessibility.force_disabled` *preference* to: `-1`

- First, in **Firefox**, in the **Address/Search** *combo box*, type `about:config` and press **enter**.

  - If applicable, click the **Accept the Risk and Continue** button.
- In the **Search preference name** *text box*, type `accessibility.force_disabled` and press **enter**.
- Click the **Edit** button and change its *value* to: `-1`
- Click the the **Save** button.

---

Here is an *example* of how I would instruct **Firefox** to open a new *window* to a given **URL** and wait for the page to finish loading.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code:*

```applescript
set theURL to "https://news.google.com/"

tell application "Firefox" to activate
delay 0.5 -- # Value may need to be adjusted if Firefox is closed.

my clickApplicationMenuCommand("Firefox", "File", "New Window")
delay 0.5
my setURLofFirefoxFrontWindowTo(theURL)
my waitForFirefoxPageToFinishLoading()

say "foobar"


--  # Handler(s) #

to clickApplicationMenuCommand(appName, appMenuName, appMenuCommand)
    tell application appName to activate
    delay 0.25
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        click ¬
            menu item appMenuCommand of ¬
            menu appMenuName of ¬
            menu bar item appMenuName of ¬
            menu bar 1 of ¬
            application process appName
end clickApplicationMenuCommand


to setURLofFirefoxFrontWindowTo(theURL)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Firefox"
            set the value of UI element 1 of ¬
                combo box 1 of toolbar "Navigation" of ¬
                first group of front window to theURL
            key code 36 --  # enter key
        end tell
    end tell
end setURLofFirefoxFrontWindowTo


to waitForFirefoxPageToFinishLoading()
    --  # Requires Firefox version 87 or newer.
    --  # Requires accessibility.force_disabled set to: -1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Firefox"
            repeat until exists UI element "Reload" of ¬
                toolbar "Navigation" of group 1 of window 1
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
            repeat while (name of UI elements of ¬
                toolbar "Navigation" of group 1 of ¬
                window 1 whose description is "Reload") ¬
                is not {"Reload"}
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end waitForFirefoxPageToFinishLoading
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Tested using **Firefox** version 91.0 (64-bit).

Note that **UI Scripting** is very kludgy and is prone to failure, especially as the version of the **OS** and or *application* change, or the *value* of the `delay` *commands* are not sufficient. That said however, with **Firefox**, this as described herein is what it takes.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: @Bro, Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and if my answer resolves your issue and you feel so inclined to mark it as the accepted answer that would be appreciated, thanks.